# filter array within array trouble

Tags: javascript

Basically I am trying to create a search that searches for a keyword within an array within another array as shown in my example below

```js
let BASKETS = [
  {
    basketName: 'one',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'apple'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'two',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'three',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'grapes'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'four',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'watermelon'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'pear'
      }
    ]
  }
]

let baskets = [...BASKETS];

function listenForInput() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#input');
  input.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
     search(input.value);
  });
}

function search(term) {
  for (let i = 0; i < BASKETS.length; i++) {
    let basketItems = [...BASKETS[i].basketItems]
    baskets[i].basketItems = basketItems.filter(x => x.itemName.includes(term));
  }
  console.clear();
  console.log(baskets);
}

listenForInput();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
```

so as you can see i am declaring the variable `BASKETS` as my source of truth, then I am duplicating the variable `BASKETS` into the new variable `baskets`.

So whats happening is i am search for the keyword within the basketItems now this works to filter down, but when i start taking characters away the `baskets` array does not repopulate the basketItems as defined by `BASKETS`.. what am i doing wrong here?

My desired result is to type in `t` and get only `watermelon` in basket `four` populated, but when i press back on the keyboard and clear the search i expect the `baskets` to be populated back to its original state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays and Objects are pass by reference. Your actual array source is being modified in this case. array structuring does the shallow cloning. Probably you need to deep clone the array source or simply use array filter throughout which will not modify the actuall array source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i was able to solve this issue by using lodash `cloneDeep` method

Comment: there's almost never a need for shallow clone, and deep clone even less...

Comment: @Thankyou if thats the case, then please post an answer of how you would tackle this problem

Comment: BASKETS.filter((item)=>{ return item.filter(//and so on)}). Outer return should be true only if item name is matched in inner filter method else false.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a deep clone sledgehammer for this -

```js
const search = (query = "") =>
{ const result =
    data
      .flatMap(({ basketName = "", basketItems = [] }) =>
        basketItems
          .filter(({ itemName = "" }) =>
            itemName.includes(query)
          )
          .map(r => ({ basketName, ...r }))
      )
  console.log('---', result)
}

const data =
  [{basketName:'one',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'apple'}]},{basketName:'two',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'orange'}]},{basketName:'three',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'grapes'}]},{basketName:'four',basketItems:[{itemName:'watermelon'},{itemName:'pear'}]}]

const input =
  document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('keyup', _ => search(input.value))
```

```html
<input />
```

If you need a specific shape, you can use generic transformations that do not mutate the input -

```js
const search = (query = "") =>
{ const result =
    data
      .map(update({ basketItems: searchByName(query) }))
      .filter(b => b.basketItems.length > 0)

  console.log('---', result)
}
```

Verify the results in your own browser below -

```js
const update1 = (o = {}, [ k, t ]) =>
  ({ ...o, [k]: t(o[k]) })

const update = (patch = {}) => (o = {}) =>
  Object.entries(patch).reduce(update1, o)

const searchByName = (query = "") => (a = []) =>
  a.filter(({ itemName = "" }) => itemName.includes(query))

const search = (query = "") =>
{ const result =
    data
      .map(update({ basketItems: searchByName(query) }))
      .filter(b => b.basketItems.length > 0)
      
  console.log('---', result)
}

const data =
  [{basketName:'one',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'apple'}]},{basketName:'two',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'orange'}]},{basketName:'three',basketItems:[{itemName:'banana'},{itemName:'grapes'}]},{basketName:'four',basketItems:[{itemName:'watermelon'},{itemName:'pear'}]}]

const input =
  document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('keyup', _ => search(input.value))
```

```html
<input />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `input` event instead of `keydown`, as below:

```js
let BASKETS = [
  {
    basketName: 'one',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'apple'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'two',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'three',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'banana'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'grapes'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    basketName: 'four',
    basketItems: [
      {
        itemName: 'watermelon'
      },
      {
        itemName: 'pear'
      }
    ]
  }
]

let baskets = [...BASKETS];

function listenForInput() {
  const input = document.querySelector('#input');
  input.addEventListener('input', () => {
     search(input.value);
  });
}

function search(term) {
  baskets = BASKETS.filter(b => b.basketItems.filter(bi => bi.itemName.includes(term)).length);
  console.clear();
  console.log(baskets);
}

listenForInput();
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" />
```